# Javascript creates an iframe, but iframe cannot get http_referer

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a Javascript code that generates an iframe like so

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
       ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://IFRAMEURL");
       ifrm.style.width = "0px";
       ifrm.style.height = "0px";
       document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

And inside this iframe URL I have PHP code like so

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

However, this iframe cannot get the http_referer I think because it's dynamically generated.

The code, when not using a dynamically generated iframe, works fine.

Is there any fix or workaround to get the HTTP_REFERER?

Edit: I also don't control the parent URL. The parent URL adds the JS code , so I can't pass any other variables.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP official documentation:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

to prevent the notice you can do

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
```

But if you looking for more robust solutions its better handle it by yourself.If you control the previous page, you can pass the URL as a parameter `site.com/page2.php?prevUrl=".urlencode("site.com/page1.php`).

Comment: The only problem is I don't control the previous page.